# is multicollinearity a problem also in classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

This might be a dumb question, but from what I'm grasping, multicollinearity seems to be uniquely a problem in regression problems, and therefore models.

Comment: What’s the problem you see in regression models?

Comment: I am not expert enough to offer advice, but I would note that multi-collinearity implies specific distribution of data in the feature space, which the model needs to learn. The higher the degree of collinearity the more there is to learn. So my hunch is that removing collinearity would yield better models with less training data.

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking about this very issue for some time. It seems like in machine learning, the multicollinearity is usually not such a big deal because it should not mess up the prediction power as such. It is problematic for estimation of the effects, for coefficients of the individual variables - hence, the problem with regression.

This post summarizes it quite well https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/168631/197070.

Answer (score 1):

*Multi-collinearity doesn't create problems in prediction capability but in the Interpretability.*

With that logic, Yes it will cause a similar issue in Classification Models too.

**LogisticsRegression**, it is very similar to LinearRegression. So I believe you can easily understand the problem with this Model.

**DecisionTree**

I will try to explain the issue with DecisionTree Classifier

*Feature Importance* -

With collinear Features, this property becomes quite unreliable.

The tree can choose any of the collinear Features to create splits and hence the two Features divide the share of Importance

*e.g. Feature Importance for 2 runs when I added a duplicate Petal L/W as Feature and removed Sepal L/W on Iris flower Dataset*

`[PL_1: 0.01351351, PW_1: 0.93507842, PL_2: 0.05140807, PW_2: 0.   ]`
`[PL_1: 0.05860548, PW_1: 0.52660473, PL_2: 0.0063161 , PW_2: 0.40847369]`

*If you use a [Permutation approach](https://explained.ai/rf-importance/) to calculate Features Importance*.

In this case, it is even worse

When you will permutate any of the Collinear features, the Model will get to manage an equivalent split using the other feature and you will not observe any dip in the score. 
*Hence, it will look like both the Features have zero importance for the Model*